# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_internal_encoding() in /home/blabla/blabla.php on line 2

Tags: php, ssh

When I run a php script over ssh like:

```
php /home/blabla/blabla.php
```

it says:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_internal_encoding() in /home/blabla/blabla.php on line 2
```

but when I run it over browser like http://blabla.com/blabla.php it works.

I already installed <kbd>mbstring</kbd> using (`--enable-mbstring`) and it is activated in <kbd>php.ini</kbd> (otherwise it cannot work over browser too)

```
mbstring

Multibyte Support   enabled
Multibyte string engine libmbfl
HTTP input encoding translation disabled
libmbfl version 1.3.2
```

What is the reason for this situation ?

Why does it give that error when I want to run my php over ssh ?

Comment: Did you activate mbstring in the php.ini that's used by the CLI SAPI, it's often a different php.ini to that used by the webserver SAPI

Comment: Yes when I run phpinfo() it says it is activated, otherwise how can it work over browser ?

Comment: when I look phpinfo I see mbstring, but when I run php -m I cant see mbstring, I dont understand anything.

Comment: Ok I rebuild apache and it works now. thanks

Answer (score 1):

It isn't that strange that it is working through the webserver but not from the command line. 
The two could very well be using different config files.

You can put `<? phpinfo(); ?>` in a .php file  and run the same php file through both the webserver and the CLI to get a better understanding.  Then you could double check the config file and make sure extension is enabled.

Another alternative (yet drastic) would be rebuilding PHP and Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Put `phpinfo();` in a .php file and run it on the server.

If 'Zend Multibyte Support' is disabled:

1. Go to the PHP configuration 'php.ini' file

   - In Ubuntu, they will be in "/etc/php/{php version}/apache2/php.ini"
     (e.g. "/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini")
2. Set: `zend.multibyte = On`
3. Restart the server.

   - In Ubuntu, run the shell command: `sudo service apache2 restart`